# What is the LINQ/Lambda equivalent to Select Count(*), SUM(someColumn) From SomeTable

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I don't think I should have to group by a particular column to return aggregations for SUM and COUNT in LINQ or lambda expressions.

Is there a quick and efficient way to reproduce the following T-SQL query in LINQ or as a Lambda Expression

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(SomeIntegerColumn) From SomeTable
```

Maybe there is something I am missing

Comment: Is it possible to get Both as a new Object? like new {SUM(col), Count(*)}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
from x in SomeTable
group x by 1 into g
select new
{
     Count = g.Count(),
     Sum = g.Sum(x => x.SomeIntegerColumn)
}
```

The trick is the "dummy" grouping that lets you compute several things in one query.

Comment: so you still have to use the group by? but pad it in with a boolean?

Comment: @ShayanZafar, I don't understand what you mean about a boolean... And yes, you have to do a grouping, because of the way Linq aggregate operators work.

Comment: By the boolean i mean the "group x by 1" does this mean that it will group if a row/object exists in the table or collection?

Comment: @ShayanZafar, since the grouping key is constant, it will be the same for every item, so all items will be in the same group.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque how do I get those properties out of the Object created by Select new?

Comment: This is from LINQ to Entities and not a regular Collection

Comment: @ShayanZafar, you can call `SingleOrDefault()` on the query (since there will never be more than one result), and just access the properties from the single returned object.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque This doesn't work because I get an error that the above code returns more than one element.

Comment: @ShayanZafar, did you copy the code exactly? There is no way this query can return more than one element...

Comment: Yes I did. my code looks just like that. just replaced the data with the link to entities context

Comment: @ShayanZafar, I don't understand why it does that... what does the generated SQL look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it without a group by you can:

```
var sumCount = 
    new { count = yourCollection.Count(), sum = yourCollection.Sum(i => i.SomeIntegerColumn) };
```

Comment: This approach enumerates the collection twice. It's not too bad if it's a small in-memory collection, but it's worse if it's a DB table, because it will cause two queries to be executed.

Comment: Good point. Group By may not be pretty but its there for a reason.

Comment: Wouldn't this require two Queries to be made? I think the previous answer can be done in one query. I don't know which one is more efficient. That can be discussed here